# Node express routes hanging after socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, routes, client

I'm building a node js web app that uses express routes and socket.io for showing online users, chat, etc.

If I establish the socket.io connection and try to navigate to any other page (via an express route), the client hangs for exactly 2 minutes.

I've tried redirecting at the client level using `windows.location.href` without success.  When running debug on the client, the route doesn't get called until after the 2 minutes expires.  So the delay is either happening on the client, or somewhere in Node/express before the route is called.

I set up the functions in a separate socket.js file to keep all the socket calls in a single location, not sure if this is causing the hangup.

Here is what me setup looks like.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
var socketio = require('./src/socket');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var users  = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', users);

socketio(server);
module.exports = app;
```

users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
   res.render('register');
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res) {   
    res.render('login');
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res) {        
    res.render('profile', {user:req.user, title:'Profile', layout:'profile'});  
});

module.exports = router;
```

socket.js

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');

module.exports = initSockets;

function initSockets(server) {
    var io = socketio.listen(server);

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        // connection code
    });
});
```

client.js

```
var home = 'http://localhost:3000';

$(document).ready(function(){   
    var socket = io(home);

    socket.on('auth', function(data){
        //  authentication code
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that you just click on a l ink in the page and it takes 2 minutes for the browser to do anything after that click?  And, if you simply comment out the socket.io connection code in the weg page, then the problem goes away?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The routes all work fine, until I establish the socket.io connection.  I can connect to a link outside the site just fine, but anything inside causes the delay.

Comment: Please show relevant client-side socket.io code.  Do you get a socket.io connection on the server?  If you look in the Chrome debugger network tab when you click on a link in your page, when does it send the request to your server?  Immediately?  Or, not for 2 minutes?  This would likely determine whether the 2 min delay is caused on client-side or server-side.

Comment: The call is immediate from the client.  So must be on the server side.  Seems like it's waiting or the connection to time out.  Searching through the code I couldn't find any timeouts or intervals set to 120000 ms.

Comment: Is server CPU busy during this 2 minutes?  Or idle?  If you do a `console.log()` in a piece of Express middleware that should get called on every request, when do you see the `console.log()`, immediately or after 2 minutes?  If you do a `setInterval(() => {console.log(Date.now());}, 250)` on your server, do you see a steady stream of output in the console during the 2 minutes or is the console silent during the 2 minutes?  As you can see, this is diagnostics to narrow down who might be responsible.

Comment: The code in the /user routes doesn't get called until after the 2 minutes.  Console is silent.  What gets called before the route?  I tried running the debugger, but I don't know what gets called before the route, so I don't know where to set the break point.

Comment: It sounds like something is clogging up your "single-threaded" node.js event queue and it takes 2 minutes to finish.  What else is your node.js app doing?